# Make a JS object go from typeof="object" to typeof="undefined"

Tags: javascript, typeof

this must be easy but I can't find the solution. I have an object that I want to now be undefined. How can I change the typeof to undefined? Thanks!

Kyle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make the object itself `undefined`, but you can make the variable that references it `undefined`.

```
  var myObj = { ... };
  myObj = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just delete it using keyword 'delete'. Then its reference will be undefined.

```
delete myObj;
```

Comment: this is what I get in my Chrome console. But i'd like to understand this better. Would you mind commenting on this?  var myObj = {};
typeof myObj; // Returns "object"
delete myObj;
typeof myObj; // Returns "undefined"

Comment: You are probably running code in global scope, where chrome nicely removes properties from global object. This won't work in IE and it doesn't work in any browser for variables in general (variables that are not global): `(function(){
    var abc = 30;
    delete abc; 
    return abc;
})();`